# Gradle sync Failed - Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-play-services' not found

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i am trying to connect my app with firebase-console.
i follow the instruction step by step.
but when i follow this step,

"The Google services plugin for Gradle contains the google-services.json file you just downloaded. Change your build.grade file to use this plugin."

project-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
      dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
      }
    }
```

app-level build.gradle

```
    ...
    // Add to the bottom of the file
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

then trying to sync, i got this error

```
Error(31,0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-play-services' not found
```

...
someone can help me fix this?
this is my code now.

project build.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kreuzell.myapplicationss"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-play-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-play-services'
```

to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the tools option on android studio and select firebox from drop down and connect using the option.
It will automatically add the configurations files

[Tools [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U5gJ.png)